# React print a component within single page size that fits component's size

Tags: reactjs, pdf, printing, components

I am trying to print a React component using react-to-print library. The snippet of code below illustrates my idea.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';

const App = () =\> {
const printRef = useRef\<HTMLDivElement\>(null);

    const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => printRef.current,
        pageStyle: `@media print {
            html, body { height: initial !important; overflow: initial !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; } } 
            @page {
                size: auto;
                margin: 0;
            }
          }`,
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print</button>
                         <div ref={printRef}>
                              print_content
                         </div>
        </div>
    );

};

export default App;
```

The auto-size option produces A4 as the result. Any other useful library that satisfies this requirement is welcome.

How to configure print function so that only 1 page will be printed out and the page size fits the component's size? The print component's dimensions are mutable, allowing flexible sizing.